# How to Import large csv file using parallel programming (particularly foreach package) in R

Tags: r, csv, import, parallel-processing

I would like to import a large dataset in R using parallel programming 
packages such as doparallel, foreach, and parallel.

Comment: What percentage of that 1.9GB do you actually need?  Are there are lot of rows or columns that are in the file, but you can filter/subset?  Is this eventually going into a database after R?

Comment: Parallelizing it isn't going to help: even if you do parallelize reading it, you then have the time spent collecting from child nodes into the main R instance. Options: (1) use a fast reader, such as `readr::read_csv` or `data.table::fread` (others exist); (2) read into each child node but process in-place (in the node, no transfer back to the main R instance) and only return/transfer the necessary aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

you can read it into `R` using `bigmemory`

```
readFile <- read.big.matrix("", type="integer", header=T, backfile =".bin", extraCols=NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. Do you know why I get  Error in read.big.matrix("nat2015.csv", type = "integer", header = T,  : 
  unused argument (backfile = ".bin")

Comment: ```nat2015.bin```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a limitation of the OS.  Here are a few options to consider.

```
system.time(read.csv('../data/2008.csv', header = T))


library(data.table)
system.time(fread('../data/2008.csv', header = T, sep = ',')) 


library(bigmemory)
system.time(read.big.matrix('../data/2008.csv', header = T))


library(ff)
system.time(read.csv.ffdf(file = '../data/2008.csv', header = T))


library(sqldf)
system.time(read.csv.sql('../data/2008.csv'))
```